# Preventing scroll bar jump while infinite scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox, infinite-scroll

In Firefox and Chrome, are there ways (perhaps using smart CSS) to prevent the scroll bar from jumping while infinite scrolling?

Common example: https://twitter.com/search?q=stackoverflow

Comment: This is a browser behavior that actually make sense, when the new content is loaded the page height is increased SUDDENLY so the scroll bar jumps to represent the correct position of the page with respect to the new content height. A possible work around could be is to slowly increase the size of the new content (display it one pixel at a time) to allow the scroll bar to slowly grow. (I have not try this solution nor have I seen it work, its just a thought)

Comment: The scrollbar jump totally makes sense but there is something awkward about it. What's annoying is that when you scroll by dragging the thumb (not by wheel) the cursor ends up outside of scroll thumb after the jump and after some time it hits the bottom of the screen - you have to move it up and grab the thumb again.
I would like to see how an implementation when the cursor jumps with the scroll thumb feels like. Most likely it would feel awkward for other reasons (unpredictable and unexpected, scroll speed jumps), and obviously then the behavior would be different when using mouse and touch.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question but I figured I would share the solution I determined best.  In order to use this you must be able to calculate the height of the entire page (or determine a max that you will allow).

So on a high level :

1) Determine height of container which content will be injected, set it.  This will prevent any scroll jumping and will give the user an accurate feel for how much content they are viewing.

2) Setup an javascript that detects position of last piece of content and when that scroll point is reached trigger loading more.

```
var scrollInterval;
function searchScroll() {
    scrollInterval = setInterval(function () {
        var lastDivInContainer = $('#results_container').children().last();
            if ((lastDivInContainer.offset().top + lastDivInContainer.height()) < ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop()) + 100) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/search/page.php",
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    clearInterval(scrollInterval);
                }
            }).done(function (response) {
                if (response != 'complete') {
                    $("#results_container").append(response);
                    searchScroll();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Any chance you can help demonstrate this technique through a live test case, ie. http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/pww88u4f/?